# No signature of method: java.lang.String.filterLine() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values:

Tags: string, jenkins, filter, jenkins-pipeline, post-build

I'm new to jenkins pipeline but I'm trying to read the console output of a failed build, and if a certain line is in the output, retry the build. To do what I have below, in Jenkins I approved these two lines in the In-process Script Approval section:

method hudson.model.Run getLog
method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild

This is what I'm currently trying in the post block after all stages run.

```
failure { 
   script {
       def file = currentBuild.rawBuild.log
       def data= file.filterLine { line ->
           line.contains('my search string')
       }
       if (data != null) {
           retry(1) {
                stage('build') 
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Here's the full error message I get:

```
Error when executing failure post condition:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.filterLine() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@ec45c79]
```

I don't understand what type of argument/value **org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2** means. Please help...

Comment: I've also tried this format:

"def data = file.find{ line-> line =~ /my search string/ }"

Answer (score 2):

Since you are just trying to see if your logs contain a string, try:

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(1000).contains("my search string")
```

Replace `1000` with however many lines of your console output you want to analyze. This is the number of lines from the bottom which will be returned as a List of type String. the `.contains` can be used for filtering.

Comment: What value will your example return? A boolean depending on the search?

Comment: @OliviaBrown Yes it will return true or false

Answer (score 1):

`currentBuild.rawBuild.log` [returns](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.html#getLog()) a string, not a file object. So the String class doesn't have the method `filterLine`. So instead you can either use `getLogInputStream()` which returns an InputStream object that has the `filterLine()` [method](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html#filterLine(java.io.Writer,%20groovy.lang.Closure)). But the better option is to either do what MB mentioned or you can do something like the below using `findAll()`.

```
def logText = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog()
def searchPattern = 'my search string'
def data = logText.readLines().findAll { line ->
    line =~ searchPattern
}
```